# Ошибка при рисовании лестницы на экране

Tags: python, python-3.x

Программа будет получать количество ступенек.
Заранее известно:

```
1 import sys
2 num_steps = int(sys.argv[1])
```

Цель напечатать на экран лесенку используя символы пробела " " и решетки "#". Например, для входного параметра (количества ступенек) 4 лесенка должна выглядеть следующим образом:

```
1   #
2  ##
3 ###
4####
```

Сделал. Анализатор дает ошибку:"Неверное решение для кол-ва ступенек 3

```
import sys
c = int(sys.argv[1])
for x in range(1, c+1):
    print(x, " " * (c - x), '#' * x)
```

Помогите решить!

Comment: Используйте параметр `sep=''`: `print(x, " " * (c - x), '#' * x, sep='')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если создать шаблон строки с автозаполнением, то можно немного упростить код:

```
import sys
num_steps = int(sys.argv[1])

fmt_template = '{}.{:>%d}' % num_steps

for x in range(1, num_steps + 1):
    print(fmt_template.format(x, '#' * x))
```

При `num_steps = 4`:

```
1.   #
2.  ##
3. ###
4.####
```

Answer (score 2):

Все аргументы функции `print`, указанные через запятую, выводятся разделенные пробелом, отсюда и нестыковка.

Можно так попробовать:

```
for x in range(1, c+1):
    print('{0}{1}{2}'.format(x, " " * (c - x), '#' * x))
```

Для `c = 3`:

```
1  #
2 ##
3###
```

Либо заменить запятую конкатенацией (знак `+`):

```
print(str(x) + " " * (c - x) + '#' * x)
```